# Proof to show that a quadrilateral is a paralellogram.

Tags: geometry, triangles, proof-explanation

I am new to this site and I don't know how to code yet, so bear with me.

I am trying to show that the quadrilateral ABCD in the picture below is a parallelogram.

[image]

I know that since triangle EBC is isosceles, angle 1 and angle 2 are of equal size. Since angle 2 and angle 4 are of equal measure, then angle 1 and angle 4 are of equal measure. Then since angle 2 and angle 3 are of equal measure, so are angle 3 and angle 4. I don't know what to do next! Please help me, thank you!!

Comment: I went to include your picture in the question, but it is too large and on its side. Could you rotate it please?

Comment: @Kundor I added the picture again the way I did before (it was correctly rotated, and it still comes out the wrong way. I'm going to try something clever.

Comment: I fixed it up. Perhaps you are using a viewer that rotates it for you, but didn't save the rotated image.

Answer (score 1):

if angle 2 = angle 3, then BC is parallel to AD.
and if angle 1 = angle 4 then DC is parallel to AB.
And if you have a quadrilateral with both pairs of opposite edges parallel to one another you have a ?